# Azure Data Factory Copy Files

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-file-copy

I want to copy files from one folder to another folder in data lake using ADF pipelines.
Ex : a/b/c/d.  TO a/b
Here a,b,c,d are folders here I don't want to copy c,d folders .I have to copy the files inside those folders to 'b' folder.

I created a pipeline using Get Metadata , For each  and in For Each I used copy activity.But here I am able to copy files with folder itself .I'm failing to remove folders.

Comment: hi sowmya, have you checked PratikLad's post? If it helps you could [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I reproduced your scenario follow the below steps:**

- In my demo container I have nested folders like a/b/c/d under d folder I have 3 files as below.
  [image]
- To copy files from folder to folder I took `Get metadata` activity to get list of files from folder.
  **Dataset for Get Metadata:**
  [image]
  **Get Metadata settings:**
  [image]
- Then I took `for-each` activity and passed the output of `Get Metadata` activities output to it.

```
    @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

- Then created `copy activity` inside for each activity and
  **created source dataset with filename parameter**
  [image]
  In file name gave dynamic value as `@dataset().filename`
  [image]
  In copy activity source gave dynamic value for dataset property filename as `@item().name`
  [image]
  Now created sink dataset with `a/b` directories only
  [image]
  and passed it to sink
  [image]

**Output**

- files copied under b folder without coping c and d folder
  [image]

Comment: Thank you for this. But my issue was there are some more folders in the 'C' and 'd' but I don't want to copy those folders .I want to copy only files in those folders .Like ---> I have d&e folders in the 'c' folder . I want to copy only files in those d&e folders .

Comment: Do you mean like your d folder has files along with folders and you want to copy only folder?

Comment: No .My question was I have some child folders inside parent folders and in that child folders I'm having some more child folders .Just I want to copy the files in those folders to target source without copying folders